# Registering OAuth authorization service middleware

Tags: owin, asp.net-core, katana

How can i register the `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware` and `OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware` in ASP.NET 5?

I tried the following:

```
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware), OAuthServerOptions);
app.UseMiddleware(typeof(OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware), new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
```

But this throws the following error:

```
System.Exception: TODO: unable to locate suitable constructor for Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware. Ensure 'instanceType' is concrete and all parameters are accepted by a constructor.
```

I'm trying to port token based authentication implemented in this ([click here](https://github.com/attilah/AngularJSAuthentication/blob/master/AngularJSAuthentication.API/Startup.cs)) application into ASP.NET 5.

I've hit a wall here, not being able to register the OAuth server middleware and OAuth Bearer authentication.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use middlewares from Katana project with UseMiddleware method in an ASP.NET vNext project. You can try UseOwin method provided here: https://github.com/aspnet/HttpAbstractions/blob/335895d9b49042312eca12a089340adf3ca0a219/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Owin/OwinExtensions.cs but I'm not sure how it's going to work.

The wisest decision here is to port your stuff to new world. You can find the OAuth Server middleware implementations here: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuth

Comment: Does "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuth" replace "Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth"?

Comment: Yes, you can think of it that way. Think that it's the next version of it. It nearly has the same API with on top the new HTTP Abstractions implemented in ASP.NET vNext.