# Cannot get both Authentication and Entity Framework working in startup.cs

Tags: oauth-2.0, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am using the most up-to-date code examples and snippets I can find, and I understand that things are changing and moving quickly.

When I use the out-of-the-box Visual Studio "vNext ASP.NET Web Application" template, then authentication and database services work just fine.

However, I think that the template is no longer up-to-date and I would like to use the latest assemblies and methodologies.

If I try to use "Microsoft.AspNet.Security.OAuth" as mentioned here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26532837/390480

then I cannot get both Authentication and Entity Framework with SQL Server to work.

What happens is that some methods or properties are no longer available.

Is there any example right now with authentication and EF 7 with SQL working?

Optimally I would like to use `UseOAuthAuthorizationServer` but that no longer seems to be an option so `UseCookieAuthentication` is fine.

Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tried the two sample applications "Music Store" and "Identiy Sample".

They would not build/run until I ran the file that comes with them named build.cmd.

So I ran this file but forgot that the last time I ran it it corrupted my system and it corrupted my system again.

Now Visual Studio keeps showing a message box saying:

```
The project system has encountered an error. 
An item with the caption "" already exists in the tree 
with the same sort order as the item being added.
```

Also after running build.cmd I now get hundreds of errors such as:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'AspNet' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I don't know what fixed it last time.  Trying to fix again now.

**UPDATE 2:**

I remember how I repaired my system now.  I recorded the steps here and will try it again now.  It's about a 1 hour process.

http://forums.asp.net/p/2013828/5795198.aspx?Re+Can+t+creat+new+project

Comment: check out https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore sample application. It has identity bits built into it. It may help you understand how to wire things up. Also, another sample which is specific to ASP.NET vNext Identity: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc

Comment: @tugberk, please see my update in original post.

Comment: VS 14 is currently a CTP product so it's possible that there are some hiccups. I can run the sample app fine through command line. Did you try that? Also, I suggest you to change the question title and structure as it's getting unclear what you are asking as you update the post :)

Comment: @tugberk, yeah, sorry the question got a bit convoluted.  Short version, "Want to see example of UseOAuthAuthorizationServer with latest OAuth and EF7 but it's gone."  But I'm just going to stick with the template that came with VS.  (And the hiccups are fine; that's what makes it fun :)

Comment: yes, I just had a careful look and I am seeing that they are probably not going to port this over to vNext. I opened up an issue for this: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/83 You can leave your comment there indicating why you want to see this middleware ported to new world.

Answer (score 0):

first get the latest KRE

with Command prompt (run as admin)

@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aspnet/Home/dev/kvminstall.ps1'))"

right click on your project and pick newer version KRE !

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxGth.png

update all your project.json packages to RC1

i.stack.imgur.com/YYAIe.png

and last part on ASP.Net 5 starter Web Template has migration files under Migration folder 
and from beta1 to RC there are some changes happened on method names (like GenerateValuesOnAdd is now GenerateValueOnAdd) need to be fixed

and you are ready to go

**** I prefer to start ASP.NET 5 Empty project and select and test everything Step by Step you can also follow that way too ***

(Sorry I want to do a better job on this but  stackoverflow doesn't let me put links or images with my reps)